# WKT to some object that will give me longitude and latitude properties

Tags: openlayers

How, in JavaScript and OpenLayers, can I pass my WKT point string to a method and get back an object that will parse the longitude and latitude into properties for me?

```
'POINT (XXX YYY)'
to
SomeObject.longitude
and 
SomeOjbect.latitude
```

Comment: use `ol.format.WKT#readFeature`

Comment: I can't find longitude and latitude (debugger on line 13) in the feature object...http://jsfiddle.net/5hdu8bdr/

Comment: To get a list of longitude/latitude from the feature just: `feature.getGeometry().getCoordinates()`

Comment: the coordinates look different `'POINT(10.689 -25.092)'` vs `[1189894.0370893013, -2887048.988883849]`?

Comment: That's because you are converting the coordinates from `4326` to web mercator projection. You can either transform your coordinates (just for use/print) using `ol.proj.transform` or use `EPSG:4326` as your map projection and let the wkt parser dont transform anything (get ride of `featureProjection` property).

Comment: Thanks for the help, if you post an answer I'll mark it! Btw, any good references to get up to speed on mapping lingo and easy for newbies : )

Comment: cool, I'll write later at home. :)

Answer (score 3):

Try grabbing the coordinates with a regex:

```
wktString = 'POINT(10.689 -25.092)';
coordFinder = /\(\s?(\S+)\s+(\S+)\s?\)/g;
allMatches = coordFinder.exec(wktString);
lon = parseFloat(allMatches[1]);
lat = parseFloat(allMatches[2]);
```

Comment: This is similar to what I was doing except I was using substring.